# Redirect in before_request()

Tags: python, flask

I'm aware that the `before_request()` function is executed before the function attached to the route is executed.

My code checks if the user is logged in in the `before_request()` function, and if they're not it redirects to the index page. However, the redirect isn't working. Here's my code:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
if(
    (
        request.endpoint != 'index' or
        request.endpoint != 'home' or
        request.endpoint != ''
    )
    and 'logged_in' not in session
):
    print("NOT LOGGED IN")
    redirect(url_for('index'))
```

This prints "NOT LOGGED IN" in the terminal, but doesn't redirect.  How do I redirect correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return the redirect, not just create it.

```
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Consider using [Flask-Login](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) rather than doing this yourself.