# Redirect using before_request in flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask, redirect, flask-wtforms

I have been working on the authentication using flask and I wanted to check if user is logged in before every endpoint. If not I want to redirect it to the login page using before request in Flask.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if((request.endpoint != 'login' or request.endpoint != 'signup' or request.endpoint != '') and 'logged_in' not in session):
        print("NOT LOGGED IN")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I have tried this but it is not working. Is there any way to redirect using before_request in Flask. Also I am not using login_manager for this.

Comment: Be more clear, what is "not working".

Comment: I guess you saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017348/redirect-in-before-request you code is just quite the same ?

Comment: Use a debugger. See why the if statement is evaluating to false, and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Yes I tried the same but its giving me this error after redirecting **This page isn’t working**.

Comment: Actually its is running in a closed loop that is every time i go on an endpoint it redirects it back to login and again the before_request function starts and it keeps on going because of the return loop. This is the actual error i am getting **127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.**

Answer (score 0):

What your saying with

```
if (request.endpoint != 'login' or request.endpoint != 'signup' or request.endpoint != '') and 'logged_in' not in session
```

is equivalent to

```
if not (request.endpoint == 'login' and request.endpoint == 'signup' and request.endpoint == '') and 'logged_in' not in session
```

what you want is

```
if not (request.endpoint == 'login' or request.endpoint == 'signup' or request.endpoint == '') and 'logged_in' not in session
```

or

```
if request.endpoint not in ('login', 'signup', '') and 'logged_in' not in session
```

Comment: I think the answer is irrelevant. It doesn't matter how I structure my if block because that would not help me in redirecting the page.

Comment: I don't follow. This will fix the "127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times" error you were having which in turn will make the redirect work.

Comment: @saneCracker007 does it work for you? If not then do you have a solution for it? If yes, please share

Comment: @Antespo , the solution provided was correct and it was working. I apologize for the delayed response.